# how to retrieve all lines with errors in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I can use

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

to load a csv file.

By default, it fails when there are any parsing errors. I understand that one can use `error_bad_lines=False` to skip the rows with errors.

But my question is:

How to get all the lines where errors occur? This way, I can potentially solve the problem for not only this particular `file.csv` but also other related files in a batch `file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv ...`

Comment: warn_bad_lines defaults to True when error_bad_lines is set to False. So you get a warning that provides the line numbers in the input file where the error occurred. What additional information are you looking for? Output looks like: 
Skipping line 4: expected 5 fields, saw 6
Skipping line 5: expected 5 fields, saw 7

Comment: @ViennaMike, I am expecting a more programmatically way of getting these information. More specifically, the above output you mentioned helps me to manually check which lines have errors. But, I would rather store the line numbers into a variable. And output all the error lines into a separate text file so that I only need to load those lines with errors next time (into a database for example).

Answer (score 1):

One easy way would be to prepend a row index number to each row.  This can easily be done with Awk or Python before loading the data.  You could even do it in-memory using StringIO or your own custom file-like object in Python which would "magically" prepend the row numbers.